# assigning object of inherited class to super class object

Tags: java, inheritance

I have two given classes A and B. 
B inherits from A.

Now in the main method of class M there is an instance z of A 
that point to an object of B.

I know that the methods of the subclass stay if a object of an inherited class is assigned to a super class.

**Question**: So why is for `z.(-6)` the method `f(double y)` of B used and not `f(int y)`?
Or in other words: Can you explain why the output gives -8.0 and 4.0 ?

```
public class A {
   public int x = 2;

   public A() {
      this.x+++;
   }

   public A(int x) {
      this.x += x;
   }

   public void f(double x) {
      this.x = (int) (x + B.y);
   }
}


public class B extends A {
   public static double y = 3;

   public double x = 0;

   public B(double x) {
      y++;
   }

   public void f(int y) {
      this.x = y * 2;
      B.y = 0;
   }

   public void f(double y) {
      this.x = 2 * y + B.y;
   }
}


public class M {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   A a = new A((int) B.y);
   System.out.println(a.x); // OUT: [5]

   B b = new B(2);
   System.out.println(b.x + " " + B.y); // OUT: [0.0] [4.0]

   A z = b;
   System.out.println(z.x); // OUT: [3]

   z.f(-0.5);
   System.out.println(b.x + " " + z.x); // OUT: [-6.0] [3]

   z.f(-6);
   System.out.println(b.x + " " + B.y); // OUT: [-8.0] [4.0] 
   }
}
```

Comment: Because `A` doesn't have a `f(int x)`. Also, use meaningful variable and method names.

Comment: The static type of `z` is `A` which does not have an`f(int)`, so method resolution at compile time will pick `f(double)`, then at runtime, dynamic dispatch will call the overridden version of that method in the `B` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example `z` is a *reference* not an object. `z` points to a `B` instance in reality whether the compiler knows it or not.

> So why is for z.(-6) the method f(double y) of B used and not f(int y)?

You have told the compiler that `z` is a reference to an `A` and this has only one method `f(double)` which can be overridden but not overloaded by a sub-class.

i.e. the signature of the method called is determined at compile time (the type the compiler things it is), not runtime (not the actual type)